# Existing project as a portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal

How do we add an existing project(not a Liferay) in the form of a URL as a portlet in the Liferay portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any existing web application running on somewhere else. You can use Liferay's iframe portlet. Just provide the URL of your application in the portlet.

Ref :
[Iframe Portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe+Portlet)